# How can I make this function as fast as the vDSP version?

Tags: vectorization, llvm-clang, vdsp

I have written the function below, which uses vDSP function calls to compute a certain result. I thought it would be faster if I rewrote it using the 128 bit vFloat data type to avoid the vDSP function calls. But my vFloat code is still 2-3 times slower than the vDSP version.

I am targeting iOS mainly, but it would be best if the code also runs well on Mac OS.

I measure the speed of these functions on arrays of length 256, which is the typical array length for my application. I want to know how to get this function to run as fast as possible because I have many others like it and I am hoping that once I figure out how to optimize this one I can use the same principles for all the others.

Here is the vDSP version, which on Mac OS is 50% faster with aggressive optimizations enabled, or 2-3x faster with less aggressive compiler settings:

```
void asymptoticLimitTest2(float limit,
                      const float* input,
                      float* output,
                      size_t numSamples){

        // input / limit => output
        vDSP_vsdiv(input, 1, &limit, output, 1, numSamples);

        // abs(output) => output
        vDSP_vabs(output, 1, output, 1, numSamples);

        // 1 + output => output
        float one = 1.0;
        vDSP_vsadd(output, 1, &one, output, 1, numSamples);

        // input / output => output
        vDSP_vdiv(output, 1, input, 1, output, 1, numSamples);
}
```

Here is my vFloat version, which I thought would be faster because it avoids all the function calls, but for my application's standard vector length of 256, is not faster:

```
    void asymptoticLimitTest3(float limit,
                              const float* input,
                              float* output,
                              size_t numSamples){

    vFloat limitv = {limit, limit, limit, limit};
    vFloat onev = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};

    size_t n = numSamples;
    // process in chunks of 8 samples
    while(n > 4){
        vFloat d = vfabsf(*(vFloat *)input / limitv) + onev;
        *(vFloat *)output = *(vFloat *)input / d;

        input += 4;
        output += 4;
        n -= 4;
    }

    // process the remaining samples individually
    while(n > 0){
        float d = fabsf(*input / limit) + 1.0;
        *output = *input / d;

        input++;
        output++;
        n--;
    }
}
```

I am hoping to get asymptoticLimitTest3() to run faster than asymptoticLimitTest2(). I'm interested to hear any and all suggestions that will speed up asymptoticLimitTest3()

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did more tests on the timing, and it turns out that the vFloat version is generally NOT slower than the vDSP version. When I did the original tests, I was calling the same function over and over again in a for loop to get the timing info. When I rewrote the loop so that it interleaves the calls with calls to other functions (as would be more normal for an actual application), then the vFloat version is faster. Apparently the vDSP version was picking up some benefit from running the same code repeatedly, perhaps because the code itself remained in the cache.